# How to stop articles printing twice with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.7

I'm trying to print each article link from this website and the article links are printing twice and only printing 5 of them.

I tried increasing my range to (1,20) which printed all ten article links but each of them twice.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = urlopen("https://www.politico.com/newsletters/playbook/archive")
target = 'C:/Users/k/Politico/pol.csv'

content = url.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")

for article in range (1,10):
    #Prints each article's link and saves to csv file
    print(soup('article')[article]('a',{'target':'_top'}))
```

I expect the output to be 10 article links with none of them repeating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the method below, works like a charm.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = urlopen("https://www.politico.com/newsletters/playbook/archive")
target = 'C:/Users/k/Politico/pol.csv'
content = url.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")

articles = soup.findAll('article', attrs={'class':'story-frag format-l'})

for article in articles:
    link = article.find('a', attrs={'target':'_top'}).get('href')
    print(link)
```

[image]Expected output is as above

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked the best for my scenario. I'm new to python so I'm wondering, in the for loop "for article in articles:" is article referring to each of the article classes in the HTML?

Comment: awesome. I'm glad i could help. Year article describes each element in the list of articles

Answer (score 1):

You can use css selector .front-list h3 > a

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.politico.com/newsletters/playbook/archive#')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
links = [link['href'] for link in soup.select('.front-list h3 > a')]
print(links)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to print your soup and see how that in every iteration, there are 2 links and are same.
Hence, it is printing twice.

take a set and put all the `str(data)`

```
a = set()
for article in range (1,20):
    a.add((str(soup('article')[article]('a',{'target':'_top'}))))

print(a)
```